# Why isn't a public texture available in a Monobehavior?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-editor

I have a simple class that has a texture:

```
using UnityEngine;
public class RayTracingMaster : MonoBehaviour
{
    
    public Texture SkyboxTexture;
    
    private void Awake()
    {  
        // This is null?
        Debug.Log(SkyboxTexture);
    }
}
```

I've dragged and dropped an image into Unity and linked it to the SkyboxTexture UI element.
But everywhere I try and reference it in the script (above) it's `null`.

[image]

Comment: Try looking at the image you put the script on not the script. Its showing you the script otherwise it wouldn’t be showing you the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you see and edited is the Inspector of the script file itself!

You referenced the texture and shader as the **"default reference"** for any new instance of this script!

Note that this would only have any effect on instances created **after** this and won't affect instances that already existed.

---

Rather search the already existing instance(s) of your component attached to any GameObject in the Scene or prefabs using `"t:RayTracingMaster"` (I suppose your `MainCamera`) and make sure that also there you have referenced the texture etc correctly!